# Do Ifrit start with the outsider skill point bonus?

Tags: pathfinder-1e

I am building an Ifrit Sorcerer, Bloodline: Elemental Fire

Since this is my first Pathfinder character, I am going through all of the bonus skills and feats, etc. to determine what I want.

I see that the Ifrit is an Outsider, of the Native subtype.

Per [this page](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Outsider), Outsiders get 6 + int modifier skill points per Hit Die.  I don't have an Int Modifier, so does that mean my starting skill points are 6 instead of 2?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From the start of the same page:

> When discussing or considering a playable race's type, it's type is
>   similar to the corresponding creature type, with a few important
>   differences.
>
> ...
>
> The second difference is that all of these race
>   types are 0-Hit Dice creatures, which means that their Hit Dice, base
>   attack bonus, saving throw progression, skill points, class
>   skills, and weapon and armor proficiencies are based on the class
>   levels each member of a race takes.

So your ifrit, being a playable race, aplies all of the [native](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#subtype-native) [outsider](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/bestiary/rules-for-monsters/creature-types#TOC-Outsider) characteristics except as noted in the second paragraph, as those characteristics are defined by your class levels, not your racial HD (that you do not have). Your only gain is darkvision 60Ft. And that several spells (and maybe some items) may not work in you, or have a different effect.

Comment: @MACN which means, that I can be targeted by those spells.  Meaning my first comment was correct.  Darkvision is my only gain from being a Native Outsider?

Comment: @DavidWilkins Spells like Enlarge Person must target a Humanoid(*any*), since you are an Outsider(Native), you cannot be the target of that spell.

Answer (score 6):

**No**

Those numbers refer to what Outsiders gain from Outsider Hit Dice, which are not the same as class levels. An Erinyes, for example, has Outsider Hit Dice. The ifrit, found [here](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/races/other-races/featured-races/arg-ifrit), advances solely by class level; they do not gain typed hit dice. As a result, like a normal player race they gain skill points based on their class level totals.

It should be noted that if you take a creature with typed hit dice (such as an erinyes), the hit dice it gains from its class levels determine its BAB, Save, and Skill Point progression for those levels. The values from its typed hit dice only apply to *those hit dice*.

Answer (score 1):

The page you linked is for determining how many skill points you're going to get in case you have some racial hit dice in the "outsider" class.
Any outsider monster you see in the Beastiary has some racial hit dice and, just as you do when you level up, they get some skill points at every level.

You don't have any outsider hit die, all your hit die are from the Sorcerer class. Therefore, feel free to ignore that page and look at your class' page instead.

Comment: Does being an Outsider have any effect on my character at all?

Comment: @DavidWilkins Yes, yes it does. It influences what spells you can and cannot be affected by, for instance.